# Can a subclass of Exception extend from another class in Java?

Tags: java, exception, inheritance

If my class already `extends` from some other class what should I do if I want an instance of my class to be thrown as an `Exception`?

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that inherits from Exception, and then WRAPS your original class as the exception payload. Composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Java does not support multiple inheritance.

The only possibility would be to **extend** your class from `java.lang.Exception`  and then **implement** other interfaces.

As suggested by JP Moresmau in another answer, you can create a class that `extends java.lang.Exception` and wraps your desired class. But in this approach you would be modifying your approach, and not making multiple inheritance as you originally wished.